# jquery find string and replace a certain text doesn't seem to work on my code

Tags: jquery, html

I want to find the word "AND" on the variable val which is passed together with index,

```
$('#hizukemade').change(function(event) {
    $('#kikanSentakushi').val('--');
        $('#DateTime').val(function(index, val) {
            //alert('index='+index+' val='+val+' indexof And='+val.indexof("AND"));
            if (val.indexof("AND")>0)
            {
              var andPos = val.indexof();
              val=val.replace("AND","AND "+event.target.value+" 23:59:00'");
              return val;
            }
            else
              return val + event.target.value+" 23:59:00'";
        });
    });
});
```

I'm using a jquery date picker and this doesn't seem to work. My alert doesn't seem to show up. Maybe there's something wrong with my syntax or something.

I wanted to post my code on jsfiddle but the jquery date picker seems not yet supported.

Comment: Please define: `doesnt seem to work` ???

Comment: `indexof()` != `indexOf()`

Comment: date picker is supported on jsfiddle, you just have to include jquery UI as a resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose typo here.

It is `indexOf()` instead of `indexof()`. Maybe that is returning `undefined`

Also, this line:

```
var andPos = val.indexof();
```

will return `-1`. I don't think it is what you are looking for. I think you are needing `val.indexOf("AND");`

Comment: thank you! but is there a way to replace all the following strings characters after the "AND"?

Comment: you would do this:  `val.replace(/AND.*/,"");`

Comment: @setsuna, you can accept my answer and upvote too `;)`

Comment: how about replace all strings before "AND"? is it /*.AND/?

Comment: @setsuna, `val.replace(/.+?AND/,"AND");`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your syntax.

```
var andPos = val.indexof();
```

Change the above to:

```
var andPos = val.indexOf("AND");
```

Each and every time you need to send in the `AND` to the `indexOf()` function.